# Why does adding 3 elements make findall not work?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

For parsing information from this url: http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.xml

```
    url = "http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.xml"
    fhandle = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx)
    string_data = fhandle.read()
    xml = ET.fromstring(string_data)
```

Why does

```
    lst = xml.findall("./commentinfo/comments/comment")
```

Not put anything into lst while

```
    lst = xml.findall("comments/comment")
```

creates a list of elements.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`Element.findall` uses a subset of the XPATH specification (see [XPATH support](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support)) based on the element you are referencing. When you loaded the document, you referenced the root element `<commentinfo>`. An XPATH `comments/comment` selects all of that element's child elements named "comments" then selects all of *their* children named "comment".

`./comments/comment` is identical to `comments/comment`. "." is the current node (`<commentinfo>`) and the following "/comments" selects its child nodes as above.

`./commentinfo/comments/comment` is the same as `commentinfo/comments/comment`. It's easy to see the issue. Since you are already on the `<commentinfo>` node, there aren't any child elements also named "commentinfo". Some XPATH processors would let you reference from the root of the tree, as in `//commentinfo/comments/comment` but ElementTree doesn't do that.

Answer (score 1):

`'.'` in the XPath already means the top-level element, here `<commentinfo>`. So your path is looking for a `<commentinfo>` *child of that*, which doesn't exist.

You can see this by cross-referencing the [example from the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#example) with the [corresponding XML](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml). Notice how none of the example XPaths mention `data`.

You want just `'./comments/comment'`.